# ERROR The import com.googlecode can not be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, javacv

I am new to android and I encountered the following problem on the following lines:

```
    import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;
    import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.*;
    import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;
```

The error is the import com.google can not be resolved.

I have included the javacv files in the project. The javacv sample programs are working fine but when I try to make my own app I am encountering this problem.

It'll be really helpful if someone can point out the mistake I am making and correct it.

I have added a screen shot of my work. Please do help. Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no package named com.googlecode in your project.You need to include opencv's libraries as mentioned in this [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#dev-with-ocv-on-android).You can then use org.opencv.{required_library_name}

Comment: Thanks for the help...but the thing is that I have included the opencv's libraries and its still showing the error...when I include these lines in xml file -        opencv:show_fps="true"
                                 opencv:camera_id="any"                     
I get an error saying that no resource identifier found for attribute camera id. It'll be great if you can help me out.

Comment: Try using OpenCV without using javacv wrapper (i.e.) using the default package provided.